# Using include in different situations

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a boilerplate that has various includes, one being:

```
    @include('nav')
```

I would like to use the same boilerplate for the CMS of my site, but use a different nav.

What would be the best way of getting the boilerplate to include a different nav when the user is using the CMS:

```
    @include('nav-cms')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of an architectural question, and the answer is that you can probably do this many, many ways. However, the answers can be Laravel specific, so here goes:

One method would be to change the include statement to be:

```
@include($navView)
```

And then either in your controller, or using view composer, you should set that variable appropriately.

Alternatively, you can do it using sections:

```
// layout.blade.php
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        @section('nav')
            @include('nav')
        @show

        @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>

// some-frontend-view.blade.php
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    Content here
@stop

// some-cms-view.blade.php
@extends('layout')

@section('nav')
    @include('nav-cms')
@overwrite

@section('content')
    CMS content here
@stop
```

That way it assumes frontend nav, and then you override it in the CMS for the CMS nav. Alternatively, instead of defaulting to 'nav' in the layout, you could use @yield, and specify it in the `some-frontend-view.blade.php` file as in the `some-cms-view.blade.php` file.

Comment: Thanks, a great answer. I have decided to create a separate boilerplate for the CMS now. I was just wondering, do you know how to namespace views. For example, in my views I now have a folder called CMS, inside is the CMS' boilerplate. A boilerplate also exists in the root of views folder. When I extend each CMS template: @extends('boilerplate'), is there an easy way to specify which boilerplate is used?

Comment: Or is it as simple as just putting in @extends('cms/boilerplate'), or is there a better way?

Comment: You use dots but otherwise yeah just follow the directory structure. I think the general Laravel convention is to stay lowercase, but I guess you can probably do it how you want to.